# How does an activity in a tab knows it switch to another tab

Tags: android

In android, I have a TabActivity with 2 tabs and each tab has it own activity (say ActivityA and ActivityB). When I am on ActivityA, and I click on ActivityB's tab, how does the ActivityA knows it is no longer the active Tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `onPause()` will be triggered in the `Activity` which is no longer visible in this situation